# How to make shortcut for .sh file?

Tags: sh

I have a file called `RunRoR.sh` i have enabled it to be executed and `run as a software` but when i double click it it doesn't do anything so in order to run it i have to do

```
~$ sh RunRoR.sh
```

Can i create a short cut or something?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [.desktop](https://help.gnome.org/admin//system-admin-guide/2.32/menustructure-desktopentry.html.en) file and place it into `~/.local/share/applications` it would then appear in the searchable applications list.

Create the file:
`nano ~/.local/share/applications/RunRoR.desktop`

Paste inside:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=RunRoR
Comment=Runs RunRoR.sh
Exec=sh ~/RunRoR.sh
Path=~
Icon=~/RunRoR.ico

Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;
```

`Name` is what will show up in the applications list.

`Comment` is just a description to help identify it.

`Exec` is the command that will be run.

`Path` is an optional working directory.

`Icon` is an optional icon file, remove this line if you don't have one.

`Terminal` specifies whether the command will run in a terminal window.

`Type` helps categorise the application in the type of .desktop file.

`Categories` is a list of applicable categories to help categorise the shortcut.

If your script generates output you want to see, then you could instead have the .desktop file launch a terminal and run the command, use the below exec command:
`Exec=gnome-terminal -t RunRoR --hide-menubar -- sh ~/RunRoR.sh`

Comment: If RoR is Ruby on Rails, then `Terminal=true` would be useful to watch logs.